# How to effectively create an object iterator that use multiprocessing of input data?

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing

I need to create an object iterator that takes a `range` input and applies some operations so iterator of prime numbers is created. Then I need to pass that prime-iterator to some `multiprocessing` method (possibly `imap`?) so that prime numbers are evaluated using parallel processing only when object iterator is called. This is my MWE:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import islice

class PrimeIterator:
    """Iterator class"""
    def __init__(self, input_stream, *, number_of_processes=mp.cpu_count()):
        """Initiate object"""
        self.input = input_stream
        self.pool = mp.Pool(number_of_processes)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return iterator"""
        self.iterator = map(is_prime, self.input)
        pool_iterator = self.pool.imap_unordered(pass_to_mp, self.iterator)
        return pool_iterator

    def __next__(self):
        """Return next item from iterator"""
        try:
            return next(pool_iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            return

def pass_to_mp(value):
    time.sleep(.4)
    return value         

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False, n
    elif n == 2:
        return True, n
    sqrt_n = int(n**0.5)+1
    return len([i for i in range(2, sqrt_n+1) if n % i == 0]) == 0, n
```

The `PrimeIterator` can be tested like this:

```
list(islice(PrimeIterator(range(100), number_of_processes=10), 10))
```

and this is the output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Despite I receive the correct data the running time is quite long. Is there some more effective `multiprocesing` implementation of given task?

Comment: The root of the problem is not `multiprocessing`, but how the primes are being computed. There is a lot of work being repeated in `is_prime`. `multiprocessing` isn't exactly a good fit for this kind of problem. Can you tell us specifically what you're trying to accomplish? For example, trying to get more comfortable with multiprocessing, or trying to find a fast way to compute prime numbers.

Comment: Actually I found out that the delay was merely because of `sleep` time in `pass_to_mp` method. I'm trying to find a memory-friendly way to compute prime numbers, but `multiprocessing` is a necessary condition. So after all this might be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Multi processing map is eager it will consume the iterable given to it as fast as it can. Here it would be better get no more than 10 items ahead. There is a way to fix this in another question that I think.